# Out-of-the-box Railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, railscasts

I'm new to rails and trying to get the Billing w/ Stripe RailsCast up and going (http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe) . I am cloned the project and built the project from the saas-after directory (https://github.com/railscasts/288-billing-with-stripe).

I then added my stripe test credentials in config/initalizers/stripe.rb , and added the subscriptions to my stripe account. I also built the rails app:

```
 bundle
 rake db:setup
 rails s
```

When I enter a valid Stripe test card i.e. 4242424242424242 I'm still getting validation issues. Error is: "There was a problem with your credit card." Same error I would get if i gave a bad credit card i.e. 123 . What am I missing to get the example up?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `models/subscription.rb`. This is where this validation error is added. Looks like Stripe didn't like the request you sent. Why don't you try to debug it by printing the error?

```
def save_with_payment
  ...
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  puts e
  logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
  errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
  ...
```

(If you use pry-debugger this would be a good time to put a `binding.pry` statement in where the `puts e` is currently ;) ).

Comment: All in one request: 

Started GET "/subscriptions/new?plan_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-26 17:26:01 -0400
  Processing by SubscriptionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"plan_id"=>"1"}

and then... 

Started POST "/subscriptions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-26 17:26:31 -0400
  Processing by SubscriptionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"45J...6WwhBDQ15HmI+QEs...k8lI1pDU=", "subscription"=>{"plan_id"=>"1", "stripe_card_token"=>"", "email"=>"jj..@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Subscribe"}
Stripe error... Empty string given for card.

Comment: So essentially on one of the callbacks the credit card token is empty.

Comment: It's not a Stripe callback that's empty -- it's what you're sending your controller via your form. `stripe_card_token` is supposed to be filled as a hidden field in your form, and it's not being done. This sounds like some part of your javascript in your credit card form is broken.

Comment: yea i am having the same problem with this...:/